# htaccess rewrite rule not working (AllowOverride on)

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

After reading several questions/answer on stackOverflow, I can't find why my htaccess rule isn't working.

This is the rule :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule login$ login.php [NC]
```

In my home folder I have the file `login.php` but when I call `http://myserverip/login` I get a 404.

When I call `http://myserverip/login.php` the page is displayed.
When I put anything in my htaccess I receive a internal server error which confirms my htaccess file is used.

So where the problem can be ?

Comment: Try this rule for testing: `RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [NC,L,R]`

Comment: This does the same...

Comment: I have a 404 not 500

Comment: If you get 404 then your .htaccess is not enabled.